# string.Replace does not work for quote

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-3.0

```
((string)dt.Rows[i][1]).Replace("'", "\\'")
```

I want the result that if any string have quote it change it into slash quote, e.g. `John's` -> `John\'s`

but the above replace function is not working fine.
it results like `John\\'s`

but if we change the code to

```
((string)dt.Rows[i][1]).Replace("'", "\'")
```

it gives the Result like `John's`

does change it anyway.

Comment: Sounds like as if you want to sanitize a SQL string. If this is true, then please realize that there are *much* better ways than manually replacing the quotes. Prepared statements for example.

Comment: @John Rash - I'm not sure your edit helped here, as far as I can tell you have corrected Azhar's code by changing "\'" to "\\'", so your edit kind of answered the question:-)

Comment: @Steve - I did not add anything I only modified the formatting, look at the [original source](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ceed45a3-95dc-4126-8d1d-3b004307214b/view-source)

Comment: @John - weird, you are right, looking at the source you clearly didn't modify this but the visual diff seems to show 
string.Replace("'", "\'"); changing to string.Replace("'", "\\'"); Apolgies for the confusion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the backslash is the escape character, you need to tell it you want to treat it like a literal string. You do this by prepending an @ to the string:

```
((string)dt.Rows[i][1]).Replace("'", @"\'")
```

Comment: The @ approach is faster when there are many things to escape and if you ever copy and paste into a different .NET language you will be happy to need only to change the @ rather than all the \\

Answer (score 9):

Try a double backslash.

`\\`

Just one backslash is an escape; two is an actual backslash.

Answer (score 4):

Use `"\\'"` or `@"\'"` for the replacement string. The backslash is the escape character in C# string literals. See the explanation of [string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) in C#: `\'` in a string literal results in just a single quote.
The reason this escape sequence exists, is because single quotes would require escaping if you were using a `char` literal (`'\''`).

The `@` indicates that you're using verbatim string syntax, which allows for multi-line strings and eliminates the need to escape characters, apart from double quote, which you would escape with double double quotes (Visual Basic style).

Answer (score 3):

Can you clarify please? Are you saying that

```
((string)dt.Rows[i][1]).Replace("'", "\\'")
```

does *not* replace a `'` with `\'` ?

Because I just tried it and it works fine. I.e. this

```
            string one = "blah'";
            string two = one.Replace("'", "\\'");

            Console.WriteLine(two);
```

Prints `blah\'`

Answer (score 1):

Replace("'", "\'") use double slash

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
private static string replace(String input)
{
   return Regex.Replace(input, "('|\")", "\\'");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   String value1 = "John Steve's";
   String value2 = "John Steve\"s";

   Console.WriteLine(replace(value1));
   Console.WriteLine(replace(value2));
 }
```

Results:

> John Steve\'s
>
> John Steve\'s

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prepare an SQL query, I think the best method is to replace a single ' for ''. For instance, if you wanto to search John O'Connor, this would work (at least in SQL Server, Access, Oracle, ...).

select ... from users where username = 'Jonh O''Connor'

Comment: If you want to prepare a SQL query like that, don't.